setInterval() с интервалом в 1 миллисекунду
Я пишу кликер на JS и столкнулся с тем, что если я с помощью setInterval() увеличиваю количество денег на 0,001 раз в миллисекунду (то есть справедливо сказать, что увеличиваю на 1 в секунду), то невооружённым глазом видно, что прирост значительно меньше, чем +1 в секунду
Смысл происходящего в том, чтобы обновлять раз в миллисекунду кол-во денег (чтобы был эффект бегущих циферок), а пользователю показывать сколько он получает денег в секунду с автокликов:
    <body>
        <h1>Money: <span id="money"></span></h1>
        <p><span id="per_sec"></span>/s</p>
        <button id="autoclick" onclick="increaseAutoclick()">+1/s</button>

        <script>
            const stats = {
                money: 0,
                autoclickValue: 0,
            };

            const moneyTag = document.querySelector("#money");
            const perSecondTag = document.querySelector("#per_sec");
            moneyTag.innerText = stats.money;
            perSecondTag.innerText = stats.autoclickValue;
В
            const increaseAutoclick = () => {
                stats.autoclickValue += 1;
                perSecondTag.innerText = stats.autoclickValue;
            };

            // увеличиваем количество денег на 0,001 раз в миллисекунду
            setInterval(() => {
                stats.money += stats.autoclickValue * 0.001;
                moneyTag.innerText = stats.money.toFixed(2);
            }, 1);
        </script>
    </body>

Методом научного тыка я обнаружил, что прирост становится ровно +1 в секунду, если добавлять раз в миллисекунду не 0.001, а 0.004:
setInterval(() => {
    stats.money += stats.autoclickValue * 0.004;
    moneyTag.innerText = stats.money.toFixed(2);
}, 1);

В чём причина? В точности setInterval(), её асинхронности или может аппроксимации десятичных дробей в JS?
И возможно есть лучшие способ реализовать такое, не через setInterval()?
Хочется чётко понимать такие базовые отношения с числами, заранее спасибо!

У setInverval есть минимальный порог. Как раз 4ms https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Огромное спасибо!) Впредь буду внимательнее читать документацию...

обрати внимание, что если браузер будет нагружен - то и этот интервал не будет выдерживаться

@Grundy да, думал и об этом тоже, спасибо)

Используйте requestAnimationFrame для анимаций. Он вызывается с той скоростью, с которой браузер способен обновлять экран. Обновлять значения чаще нет смысла. Интервал вызова может оказаться неравномерным, надо написать функцию которая будет менять экран в зависимости от прошедшего времени:


const counter = document.getElementById('counter').firstChild;

const start = performance.now();

const frame = () => {
    const dt = (performance.now() - start) / 1000;
    counter.nodeValue = dt.toFixed(2);
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
};
requestAnimationFrame(frame);
<span id="counter">0</span>




Я с самого начала думал о том, что забивать стек постоянным вызовом setInterval() раз в миллисекунду это не лучшая затея сразу по многим причинам (особенно если приложение разрастётся в будущем).
И размышлял о применении performance.now(), а о requestAnimationFrame слышу первый раз.
Вы всё сложили воедино, большое спасибо!)

requestAnimationFrame передает в callback время, которое прошло с прошлого рендера

@Grundy, это правда. Чтобы получить интервал надо колдовать со временем старта анимации (если start не определён, заполнить его в первом вызове). Я такое недолюбливаю, поэтому не использую параметр, а считаю время сам. Есть ещё технический момент - при использовании параметра анимация начинается с первого вызова колбека. Но это не правда, анимация начинается когда программист сказал, не когда браузер соизволил первый фрейм отрендерить. Разница не велика, но она есть. Кроме того её можно сделать большой если поколдовать над браузером (страничку в фон отправить).
